# Check if function belongs to a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection

I'm trying to write a documentation testing tool which checks whether the docstrings match the actual function signature (among other things). However, I've run into a bit of a roadblock. I can't find a way to figure out whether a given function belongs to a class or not.

```
import inspect

def func1():
    pass


class Foo:
    def method(self):
        pass

print(inspect.ismethod(func1))  # prints False
print(inspect.ismethod(Foo().method)) # prints True
print(inspect.ismethod(Foo.method)) # prints False - I want something that prints True here
```

The problem is that methods usually have `self` as their first parameter, and this is never documented (for obvious reasons). This would cause my tests to fail, since they'd encounter a parameter that's not documented.

I would prefer to not explicitly check if the first parameter is called `self` and skip it, because a) nothing prevents a function from having a parameter called `self` and b) the name `self` itself is a matter of convention (so you could have a method with a first param that's called `this_is_definitely_not_self`) and my tool would fail in either case. I also can't just initialize an object and check if the function is a method, because this would fail with any class that takes required parameters in its `__init__`.

So the question is, is there any way I can detect if a function is a method *before* it is actually bound to an object? Or do I need to resign myself to just checking if the first parameter is called `self`?

Comment: When you're iterating over the members of a class, you know that the attributes that are functions are methods of that class.

Comment: You could look for a `.` in the function name.  `inspect.ismethod(Foo.method) or '.' in Foo.method.__name__`

Comment: @patrick `Foo.method.__name__` will just be `method`. `__qualname__` might work for that though.

Comment: @kindall while this is true _if_ you're iterating through the members of a class, I'd like each test to work on arbitrary callables and then have a separate test runner-type entity that does the job of discovery and iteration.

Comment: The thing is, that functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html); **any** function can be added to a class and become part of it. Or you can manually bind a function to an instance.

Comment: You can, at best, detect that a function was originally defined in a class body, semantically speaking. **That's it**. What is the actual use case you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Also, any reason why the docstring must have the function signature in it? Why not **generate** that signature when you are generating your documentation?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The idea is to build a documentation testing tool that checks for function signature mismatches between `numpydoc` documentation and the actual code. Essentially something that you'd run against your code along with your unit tests, ensuring that your docs don't go out of date. When doing this, because `self` is not typically documented as a parameter, the test fails for functions that _would be bound if the class was instantiated, but aren't because it isn't_. I'm simply looking for a clean way of determining if something is be a bound method without needing to make an object.

Comment: I should not be the first to think this. But since nobody is talking about it, it  must not be right for this case. So, please tell me why not do a `'method' in dir(Foo)`.

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 because I want to be able to check this on an arbitrary object. Consider that I'm testing 100s of functions/methods in 10s of classes. Given an arbitrary callable from this list, I want to have a way of detecting whether it belongs to a class (any class), so I can exclude `self` from the parameter checking, or whether it's free-standing, so I can check all the parameters.

Answer (score 6):

One option is [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__). For methods this includes the class name which you can use. This is one of the reasons why it was added:

> [`definition.__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__)
>
> The qualified name of the class, function, method, descriptor, or generator instance.

See [PEP 3155's proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/#proposal) for more on this attribute.

Of course, since `__qualname__` is set during class definition, one can get false-positives when functions are dynamically added to a class. So, this answer basically covers the question of if a function has been *defined* in a class.

So, there's no clear-cut way to detect this since, a function defined inside a class and accessed via the class and a function outside a class have no difference. (except for `__qualname__` in most cases).

A sensible course of action would be to use the `__qualname__` as a "quick" check to see if a function has been defined inside a class and, if that is `False`, fall back to checking for `self` with the [`inspect.signature` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) and `'self' in signature(func).parameters`.

You won't be able to cover all cases, this is Python and I can do pretty much anything I'd like. Purportedly we are all consenting adults, though. :)

Comment: Ouch! That's a nasty gotcha, I can see it leading to some really hard-to-find bugs. Not sure it's better than just checking for `self` in that case :\ Have an upvote in any case!

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi yup, and I can see how the approach of checking for `self` can also lead to nasty places. I don't believe there's a single approach that covers all edge cases; it seems you'll need to combine approaches.

Comment: I might just stick to checking for `self` actually. Since this is a documentation testing tool, I think I can reasonably make the assumption that anyone who cares enough to run it, will care enough to not make totally stupid decisions like renaming `self` :p

Comment: Plus, I don't think I've ever seen in-the-wild code that used `self` in an unbound function or called the first parameter of a bound method anything other than `self`. I have certainly seen code that adds methods to objects/classes at runtime though (and have even written some when auto-generating tests)!